# Formatting Cells in a data gridview based on a value (any cells)

Tags: datagridview, formatting, grid

I have an application that that is comparing two tables from different locations (across the world) 
Each pair of tables has a different amount of columns but all cells will be a true or false response on each row column that is being compared. to load the data i am doing a dgvMatching.datasource = myds.table[0] so can not preform formatting on the load.
so i have seen a number of examples of for each row and for each cell and format that way. but a grid could be 30 col by 3000 rows that would be about 90k iterations. would it be better to just change my load method and format on the load?? examples please.

Comment: There are two (2) tables or just one (1)? When you say you are “Comparing” tables, HOW are you comparing these tables? Table1.Cell[x,y] = Table2.Cell[x.y]? Examples please… For what? What examples are you looking for but more importantly what have you tried? You may want to peruse… [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) …  AND [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i am bringing back the off site table to the local db as a temp, i compare each row/col data for each row that has a non matching value i am populating the DGV with the key values, and a True or false for each column/row data example i have 5 col with col 1, 2 keys (which will batch) but col 3,4,5 may not match so i would get a 1,2, true, false, true for one row the next could be 2,3,false, false, true. I want to highlight the False in red to make it faster for the user to find the offending value to research..

Comment: Without seeing how you may be doing this. What you describe sounds like a fairly simply query on a data table. Show me the records where columns 3, 4 or 5 are false. This would filter the table to display ONLY the rows where the values are false. If you need to high light or format a cell depending on its value is another story. You could loop through the data or set up some cell formatting to change color if the cells value is false. Something similar to Excels conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the line `dgvMatching.datasource = myds.table[0];` simply add the `CellFormatting` event to the `dgvMatching` `DataGridView`. Like below:

```
private void dgvMatching_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Value != null) {
    if (e.Value.ToString().Equals("false"))
      e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
  }
}
```

Comment: so would this be checking every cell after it is loaded

Comment: Actually it will do it while it loads. Or if a cell changes value. Like a conditional formatting in excel.

Comment: Ok so i added the dgvMatching_cellformating{} to my code but it is never called?

Comment: I assume you are using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes i am using VS c#

Comment: In the designer, click on the `DataGridView` and look at its properties. Under the event properties you will see a row called `CellFormatting`. To the right is an empty box… click on it and you should be able to select the `dgvMatching_CellFormatting` event. This will load the event so it will be called.